# Model Child object is not correctly removed in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC master-detail view based on a master-detail model and a delete button for each detail record.

On delete button pressed, I post the ID to be deleted and the whole model, I remove the correct detail record from the model and return it to the view.

The problem is that the view renders incorrect detail records.
It actually deletes the last record no matter what was pressed.

The models

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> CustomerContacts { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}
```

The controller actions

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer(){ ID=1, Name="CustOne", Description="Descr1"};

        Contact contact1 = new Contact() { ID = 1, CustomerID = 1, ContactName = "Cont_One", ContactEmail = "a@b.com" };
        Contact contact2 = new Contact() { ID = 2, CustomerID = 1, ContactName = "Cont_Two", ContactEmail = "b@c.com" };
        customer.CustomerContacts = new List<Contact>();
        customer.CustomerContacts.Add(contact1);
        customer.CustomerContacts.Add(contact2);

        return View(customer);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string btnSubmit, Customer customer)
    {
        int CustomerContactID = Convert.ToInt32(btnSubmit);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(customer);
        }

        int indexOfCust = customer.CustomerContacts.FindIndex(c => c.ID == CustomerContactID);
        customer.CustomerContacts.RemoveAt(indexOfCust);

        return View(customer);
    }
```

The view:

```
    @model MyMVCProblem.Models.Customer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    for (int i = 0; i < Model.CustomerContacts.Count; i++)
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact Name</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerContacts[i].ID)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerContacts[i].ContactName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerContacts[i].ContactName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Contact e-mail</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerContacts[i].ContactEmail)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerContacts[i].ContactEmail)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="Submit" value="@Model.CustomerContacts[i].ID">Delete</button>
        <br /><br />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to clear ModelState.
Example bellow:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string btnSubmit, Customer customer)
    {
        int CustomerContactID = Convert.ToInt32(btnSubmit);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(customer);
        }

        int indexOfCust = customer.CustomerContacts.FindIndex(c => c.ID == CustomerContactID);
        customer.CustomerContacts.RemoveAt(indexOfCust);
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(customer);
    }
```

Comment: This solves my problem! Nonetheless, I would like an answer to whether this is a framework bug or not... :)

Answer (score 1):

Something I would suggest, but am not sure if this will actually address your issue, is to use a partialview and an $.ajax call to the delete function. In other words, you could render your CustomerContacts tables in a partial view, which uses a List model. This way, on the first load of the page you could use

```
<div id="customerContactsList">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_CustomerContactsList", Model.CustomerContacts); } 
</div>
```

Then you can have your loop which renders the tables within that partial. Once you have implemented this, you can use a POST method in the controller e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteCustomerContact(int id)
{
  // Call the delete function 
  // e.g. DeleteContact(id);
  // Then re-read your contacts list
  List<CustomerContacts> contacts = GetContacts(...);

  return PartialView("_CustomerContactsList", contacts);
}
```

On your form code, add a callback for the delete button to call the said method, and on success render just the partial view with the list. Just need to add an ajax call and bind it to the click event

```
$('btnDelete').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'DeleteCustomerContact',
            type: 'POST',
            data: customerContactId,
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function ( result ) {
                  $('#customerContactsList').html(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
});
```

Now this does not guarantee to solve your problem, since I am not sure what the actual cause was, but this is a quite clear approach, since the customer contacts list is always refreshed once the delete method is called.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is a good approach and I upvoted. Yet, through this question, I would like to figure out if there is an issue in the mvc framework, when handling complex models..